# Tight estimates for binomial summation

Tags: co.combinatorics, asymptotics, binomial-coefficients, random-permutations, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

Is there tight estimates for the following logarithmic summation ($\gamma\in(0,1)$)

$$\ln\Bigg(\sum_{t=\frac{n^{}}2-\gamma n^\gamma}^{\frac{n^{}}2+\gamma n^\gamma}\sum_{\ell=\frac{n^{}}2-\gamma n^\gamma}^{\frac{n^{}}2+\gamma n^\gamma}\sum_{k=0}^t\binom{\ell}{k}\binom{n-\ell}{t-k}\Bigg)?$$

Is it roughly bounded above by $$\ln\Bigg(poly(n)\sum_{k=0}^t\binom{\ell}{k}\binom{n-\ell}{t-k}\Bigg)$$ for some **minimal** choice of $$\sum_{k=0}^t\binom{\ell}{k}\binom{n-\ell}{t-k}?$$ The summand though seems amenable to Cauchy-Schwarz gives very loose bounds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By [Vandermonde's identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde%27s_identity), $$\sum_{k=0}^t\binom{\ell}{k}\binom{n-\ell}{t-k}=\binom{n}{t},$$
so the triple sum reduces to
$$
\sum_{t=n/2-\gamma n^\gamma}^{n/2+\gamma n^\gamma}\sum_{\ell=n/2-\gamma n^\gamma}^{n/2+\gamma n^\gamma}\binom{n}{t}
=\sum_{t=n/2-\gamma n^\gamma}^{n/2+\gamma n^\gamma}(2\gamma n^\gamma+1)\binom{n}{t}
=(2\gamma n^\gamma+1)\sum_{t=n/2-\gamma n^\gamma}^{n/2+\gamma n^\gamma}\binom{n}{t}.
$$
Now $\sum_t \binom{n}{t} \le 2^n$, so
$$\ln\left(\sum_{t,\ell,k}\right) =\ln(2\gamma n^\gamma+1)+\ln\left(\sum_{t=n/2-\gamma n^\gamma}^{n/2+\gamma n^\gamma}\binom{n}{t}\right) \le \ln(2\gamma n^\gamma+1)+n\ln 2.$$

Comment: If we had $k=t-\gamma t^\gamma$ to $k=t$ would we be able to achieve $n\ln2- o(n)$?

Comment: @Robplatt https://mathoverflow.net/questions/350373/tight-sublinear-estimates-for-partial-binomial-summation.