# Tight sublinear estimates for a triple partial binomial summation

Tags: co.combinatorics, asymptotics, binomial-coefficients, entropy, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

Is there tight estimates for the following logarithmic summation ($\gamma,\gamma'\in(0,1)$ and $\mu,\mu'>0$)

$$\log_2\Bigg(\sum_{t=\frac{n^{}}2-n^\gamma\sqrt{\mu\ln n}}^{\frac{n^{}}2+n^\gamma\sqrt{\mu\ln n}}\quad\sum_{\ell=\frac{n^{}}2-n^\gamma\sqrt{\mu\ln n}}^{\frac{n^{}}2+n^\gamma\sqrt{\mu\ln n}}\quad\sum_{k=\frac t2-n^{\gamma'}\sqrt{\mu'\ln n}}^{\frac t2+n^{\gamma'}\sqrt{\mu'\ln n}}\binom{\ell}{k}\binom{n-\ell}{t-k}\Bigg)?$$

I am hoping it might give $n - f(n)$ bound where $f(n)$ is $\omega(\ln n)$ or at least $\Omega(1)$ for diagonal case of $\gamma=\gamma'=\frac12$ at some $\mu,\mu'>0$.

Relevant problem is in [Tight estimates for binomial summation](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/350336/tight-estimates-for-binomial-summation/) (and perhaps an upper bound **possible** might be $$\log_2\Bigg(\underbrace{n^{2\gamma}\mu(\ln n)}_{\substack{\mbox{coming from}\\\mbox{outer two}\\\mbox{summations}}}\binom{n}{n/4}\Bigg)<n H(\frac14+\epsilon)<0.82n$$ at any $\epsilon>0$ since $t/2=n/4$ might be close to the value that yields the bound (together with loose upper bound from [Vandermonde's identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde%27s_identity) for inner sum)).

Comment: what does at least $\gamma=\gamma'=1/2$ mean? $\min\{\gamma,\gamma'\}\geq 1/2$?

Comment: No just for the diagonal case at 1/2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This conjecture does not hold even in the case $\gamma=\gamma'=1/2$.

Indeed, consider the values of $\ell,t,k$ such that 
$$|\ell-n/2|\ll\sqrt n,\ |t-n/2|\ll\sqrt n,\ |k-t/2|\ll\sqrt n,$$
where $A\ll B$ or, equivalently, $B\gg A$ means that $|A|\le CB$ for some universal real constant $C>0$; as usual, $A\asymp B$ means that $A\ll B\ll A$. 
By what was shown in [this answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/350722/36721), 
$$\binom\ell k\asymp\frac{2^\ell}{\sqrt\ell}\,e^{-u^2/2},$$
where 
$$u:=\frac{k-\ell/2}{\sqrt{\ell/2}}\ll1, $$
so that 
$$\binom\ell k\asymp\frac{2^\ell}{\sqrt n}.$$
Similarly,
$$\binom{n-\ell}{t-k}\asymp\frac{2^{n-\ell}}{\sqrt n},$$
whence
$$\binom\ell k\binom{n-\ell}{t-k}\asymp\frac{2^n}n.$$
Hence (in the case $\gamma=\gamma'=1/2$), your big triple sum is 
$\gg \dfrac{2^n}n\,n^{3/2}$
and hence 
$$\log_2(\text{the triple sum})-n\gg\ln n.$$

Comment: What is the correct asymptotic?

Comment: @VS. : I think the correct asymptotics for your $f(n)$ is $\asymp-\ln n$ if $\gamma=\gamma'=1/2$; otherwise, it will much depend on $\gamma$ and $\gamma'$. However, please ask any additional questions in separate posts.